# Client.roles.cache.size => undefined | Discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

`client.roles.cache.size` doesn't seem to work for me in v12, just says that `cache` is undefined

Any alternatives for how I can get the **total number** of roles the bot is currently instantiated with across all guilds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Client` has no property called `roles`. This property belongs to `Guild`.

---

You can map your Guilds by `roles.cache.size` and get the sum of the array.

```js
const roles = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.roles.cache.size);
console.log(`Total Roles: ${roles.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)}`);
```

Comment: Was a property on djs v11, just putting it here so I don't look stupid